# compiling with multiple include paths c language

Tags: c, include, dependencies

I know there are tonnes of stuff out there for this kind of problem, but whenever I try the solution they give, it doesn't work, so I just figured I would get a proper custom solution for me, then work backwards from there.

I have a working directory where I have my main in.

lets call it /work

and inside of that directory I have several other folders which I want to include in my main and these each have dependancies in the other folders.  For now lets just go over two of them.  /work/clibs/linked_list.c which has a dependancy on /work/common/logger.h

So far I have put an include in linked_list.h that says

```
#include "../common/logger.h"
```

which should resolve the dependency but it doesn't.  Neither of these files have a main in them but it shouldn't be bugging me about dependencies if that was the only problem.

Comment: Did you try to add `/work` directory to your compiler include paths (for `GCC` you would pass `-I/work`).

Comment: Does _linked\_list.c_ _#include_ linked_list.h? Files that define functions that are to be used by other files--libraries--don't need a _main_, by the way.  If you're getting an error message, please share it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any files you include in your main program are treated like added code parts to your main program, which makes any #include inside them be treated as if it was an #include done from the main program itself.

Your main program is at "/work" and you are including "clibs/linked_list.h". In "clibs/linked_list.h", change "../common/logger.h" to "common/logger.h" and it should work.

Comment: Ok that helped, half the problem was what you guys mentioned, but the big thing was that I was using cygwin and trying to figure out the -I directory from there is a nightmare...  linux uses '/' as you all know and windows uses '\' so I was trying to figure out whether it was using linux directory structure or the windows one.  Turns out it was a mixture.  It needs a windows directory so "C:..." but it needs the linux '/'

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the #include "../common/logger.h" is wrong. You must have other mistakes ,can you give us a complete code?